# Optaplanner, update shadow variables after every step

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to add moves selectors which consider the state of the current working solution. For example, suppose in the cloud balancing problem I was trying to make a move which preferentially moved a process onto a computer which already holds few processes. I have a shadow variable which tracks the number of processes on the computer, then I have a valueSelector which implements SelectionProbabilityWeightFactory that gives a higher weight to computers with fewer processes.

This setup works fine and produces the moves that I want. But it is terribly slow because it is updating the shadow variable far more often than I need it to. Since I am not using this shadow variable for scoring, I don't need it to be updated after every move attempted during the step. I only need the shadow variable to be updated after each accepted move (i.e. the end of the step).

Alternately, I could use a custom move factory, but that requires that every computer have its process count fully re-calculated at each step. This means I would lose the incremental calculation benefit I get with the shadow variables.

So is there a way to force shadow variables to update after each step, rather than after each move. Or is there a better way to track the status of the working solution for use in move selectors?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news first:

It's not possible to have `VariableListener` only update a shadow variable per step and not per move. And it's unlikely we'll ever want to allow that particular change, as it would hurt the predictability and integrity of the state of the domain model between move iterations. This could create a lot of havoc, including multiple forms of corruptions, if used slightly incorrectly.

---

Good news next:

Yes, **you need to calculate some state per step to generate moves efficiently**. This is a common problem I've run into a few times before too.
But why put that on the domain model? It doesn't belong there.

It belongs on the the move selector. For example, if you use a `MoveIteratorFactory`, that has a method called `phaseStarted()` (called when the phase starts) and a method `createRandomMoveIterator()` (called when a step starts even with SelectionCacheType.JIT).

Some something like this should do the trick:

```
public class MyMoveIteratorFactory implements MoveIteratorFactory<...> {

    default void phaseStarted(ScoreDirector<...> scoreDirector) {
    }

    Iterator<Move_> createRandomMoveIterator(ScoreDirector<...> scoreDirector, Random workingRandom) {
        List<Computer> alreadyUsedComputerList = ...; // runs once per step
        return new MyIterator(alreadyUsedComputerList, workingRandom);
}
```

Now, the plot thickens when multiple move selectors need to reuse the same calculation. That's where SupplyManager comes into play, which is not public API. But this is definitely a good requirement for our "move streams API" experiment that we'll do next year.

Comment: The issue is that my domain model can have thousands of planning entities. So I want to make the "runs once per step" function run as incrementally as possible given that only one or two of the entities will change per step. In the `createRandomMoveIterator` is there any way to get information about the move made in the previous step which I could use to limit my calculations?

Comment: Not with MyMoveIteratorFactory, that is a simplified plugin point that doesn't have that much power. Internally, a custom MoveSelector does have that much power - through SupplyManager for example, but that deep impl territory (too much to explain here). To give an example, the SwapMoveSelector impl uses a  SingletonInverseVariableSupply and that supply is kept up to date incrementally. What kind of use case are you working on?

Comment: I have a gut feeling that you not be looking at the right thing to optimize, unless your score calculation speed is already above 10 000 and it needs to faster (which is possible through these advanced techniques).

Comment: Our calculation speed is above 10,000, but found that adding a move selector which utilized shadow variables would slow us down a good bit. I just wanted to see if there was a more efficient way we would keep track of the current solution for use in move selectors.